# "pre-paid card" or "prepaid card?"

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

Should I write "pre-paid debit card" or "prepaid debit card"? I found [a discussion about the same topic on wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/prepay-pre-pay-or-pre-pay.2936899/)

Comment: I suggest you look the word up in Merriam-Webster online dictionary and tell us what it says and why what is says leaves you with a question.

Comment: @Clare thanks, the dictionary had a very good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [merriam-webster article about hypens in prefixes](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_prefixes.htm), I am most confident the answer is "prepaid." You should avoid the hypen when possible.

Thanks to @Clare for the comment.

Comment: Also the entry at *prepay*, which my browser directed me to when I searched for *prepaid*, does indeed give *prepaid* as the correct form. The M-W dictionary is the first place to look, according to the *Chicago Manual of Style*.